# Using pipes in comment executed using Plink from PowerShell

Tags: shell, powershell, ssh, plink

In PowerShell, I use Plink to ssh on to a NetScaler device.

Everything works fine, but it takes a very long time to run the script because of the amount of data downloaded from the remote device to the local machine, where I'm running PowerShell.

Here is the script:

```
$log = C:\plink.exe -batch -l User -pw PWD 10.1.1.1 "shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz""
```

To improve the performance, I need to reduce the amount of data transferred from the device.
All I need is just the first part of the domain `\w+\` so I tried to add `| cut –d . –f 1` but I get this:

```
cut : The term 'cut' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:144
+ ... hell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f ...
+                                                               ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cut:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I’ve tried different ways to escape the `|` and trired putting the command into a variable or in to a file and using the `–m` switch.

Everything comes out with the same result.

The `cut` command works fine, when I use PuTTY to ssh to the device.

Is this problem with PowerShell, Plink or both? Can I use the `cut` command without a pipe? Or is there another way to return just the `\w+\` part?

Here's the output from various attempts to get the `cut` working  (not allowed to upload screenshots from work)

```
PS C:\windows\system32> C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"
 Done
                                                      ^^^
ERROR: No such command
C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe : ERROR: No such command
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS shell  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: No such command:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
PS C:\windows\system32> C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS "shell `"zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1`""
Done
                                                        ^^^
ERROR: No such command
C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe : ERROR: No such command
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS "shell ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: No such command:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS C:\windows\system32> C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS shell zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1
cut : The term 'cut' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:122
+ ... shell zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f ...
+                                                               ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cut:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Update
@Martin:
when I try

```
"shell `"zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1`"`nexit`n" | C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS
```

I get:

```
shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"
exit


Done
> shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"
grep: unknown directories method
ERROR: 
> exit
Bye!
```

If I take out the back-tick Quotes (`")

```
"shell zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1`nexit`n" | C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS
```

This is the response:

```
Done
> shell zgrep -oE '\w+\.aramco\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1
                                                            ^^^
ERROR: No such command
> exit
Bye!
```

Comment: I cannot imagine, how you could get the same problem with `-m`.

Answer (score 0):

The outer quotes are not needed by Plink and just complicate parsing. This should work:

```
$log = C:\plink.exe -batch -l User -pw PWD 10.1.1.1 shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f"
```

If you want to keep the outer quotes, you have escape the inner quotes:

```
$log = C:\plink.exe -batch -l User -pw PWD 10.1.1.1 "shell `"zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f`""
```

Comment: Its the same problem. Anything I put after the `|` PowerShell thinks it needs to run the command. Isthere an alternative to using `|`

Comment: Works for me. Show us PowerShell console screenshot with the command and the (error) output.

Comment: Cant upload screen shoots from work. Hopefully the updates I made to the question are readable.

Comment: The attempts according to my suggestions show *"C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe : ERROR: No such command"* - There's no reference to PowerShell having problems with the pipe. The error message probably comes form the server, so you are a step further. Show us a transcript of PuTTY session, where you are executing the same command.

Comment: From Putty, only one that works id `C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"`

Comment: Do you really mean that you run `plink.exe` from PuTTY?

Comment: not sure what you mean by run Plink.exe from PuTTY. I have tried using command line feature of PuTTY, but still no joy.

Comment: I mean if you really run this literal command in PuTTY, including the `plink.exe` path: `C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"`. Or if you actually run only the `shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"`

Comment: running Plink.exe from PuTTY did not work (is it possible???). In Putty I ran `shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1"`. I can pipe a grep without issue, `shell "zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | grep www` works as expected. could it be an issue with environment variables (or the Unix equivalent)

Comment: No you should not run Plink from PuTTY. But [earlier you have claimed to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135004/using-pipes-in-comment-executed-using-plink-from-powershell/44135359?noredirect=1#comment75326426_44135359). That's why I asked. - Yes, it can be environment issue. Try adding `-t` switch to `plink.exe`.

Comment: The `-t` swtich did not help or did not make any difference.

Comment: OK, than as a last resort option: `$log = "shell \`"zgrep -oE '\w+\.some\.com' /var/log/ns.log.0.gz | cut -d . -f1\`"\`nexit\`n" | C:\NetScalerBackup\plink.exe -batch -l $un -pw $pwd $PrimaryNS`

Comment: I've made an update to the main question. but your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Actually, all my suggestions work. It's your server that handles these things strangely. Your question is no longer about Plink or PowerShell. And as such it's off-topic here.